# interprocess communication using pipe

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe, ipc

I want to receive data from two microcontollers through USB and UART respectively and intergrate and synchronize the data (with a timestamp) in the main process.
Is it a good decision to use multiprocess instead of multithread? I want the processes to work fully in parallel.

For the interprocess communication, I decided to use Pipe (as it is said to be faster than Queue...)

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process,Pipe

def read_uart(uart_conn):
    while True:
        reading =uart.readline()
        uart_conn.send(reading)
    
def read_usb(usb_conn):
    while True:
    reading =usb.readline()
    usb_conn.send(reading)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_usb_conn, usb_conn = Pipe()
    parent_uart_conn, uart_conn = Pipe()
  
    process_usb = multiprocessing.Process(target=read_usb, args=(usb_conn,),).start()
    process_uart = multiprocessing.Process(target=read_uart, args=(uart_conn,),).start() 

    while True:
        if parent_uart_conn.poll():
            print(parent_uart_conn.recv())
                                             
        if parent_usb_conn.poll():
            print(parent_usb_conn.recv())
```

I want to receive the data from each process and print out in the main process as soon as the main process receives the data.
But my code above doesnt work as I expected.
How can I make the code better?

***update***
As the process_uart sends data more frequently than process_usb does,
it prints out only data from process_uart
so I changed code like :

```
while True:
    if parent_uart_conn.poll():
        print(parent_uart_conn.recv())

        if parent_usb_conn.poll():
            print(parent_usb_conn.recv())
```

It seems to work but I feel bad about the code...
I want to print out the data from each process as soon as they send the data to the main process.

Comment: what means "doesnt work as I expected."? Do you get error message? Show in question full error message. Is this freezing? Describe it in question. We can't run code so we can't know what is wrong and test it.You could also use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you get with `poll()`

Comment: it tested code and I found typo - in second `if` you use `parent_usb_conn.recv()` (USB) but it need `parent_uart_conn.recv()` (UART).

Comment: thank you so much furas! I corrected what you mentioned and added more detail

Comment: in new version you have different indentations and `if parent_usb_conn.poll():` is checked only when `if parent_uart_conn.poll():` gives `True` - so it can gives output for `USB` only when there was output for `UART`. I would use indentations from older version.

Comment: Oh I agree with you. You helped me out Furas! Thanks for your opinion.